# how to does not record in sqlite if it is already in table

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have app in which i am inserting data in sqlite table i want that if data is already inserted then it should not insert same record here is my code for inserting data.

here is code with insert statement for inserting data

```
       - (void) addCoffee:(NSString *)dbPath {

        if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into library(userID,contentAddedDateTime,contentType,contentTitle,contentSource,contentDescription,categoryTitle,subCategoryTitle,organizationCode,userName) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

       if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 


       if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


    }



  sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [userID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

  sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [contentAddedDateTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

  sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [contentType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

  sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [contentTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

  sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [contentSource UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [contentDescription UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [categoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [subCategoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [organizationCode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else
    //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
    coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

//Reset the add statement.
sqlite3_reset(addStmt);


   }
```

Comment: What is not working? have u tried returning row count to see if record is already inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (int) GetCount :(NSString *)UserID
{
[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
[self initializeDatabase];

int count = 0;


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbfav2table.sqlite"];
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *sql_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT count(*) FROM tablename WHERE userID='%@'", UserID];

    const char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql_str UTF8String];
     NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlStatement]);

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {

        while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {
            count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            NSLog(@"count for %@ is %i",UserID,count);
        }

    }
    else

 {
        NSLog( @" Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );

 }

    // Finalize and close database.
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

return count;
}
```

if it returns count = 1 it means there is already a value with same userId exist, else there  is no such value. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should write select query with a unique column. lets say ***userID*** in your case

const char *sql = "select * from library where userID=%@“;

if record exist than enter else skip